# How to use By instead of WebElement in Java PageFactory?

Tags: webdriver

This works:

```
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(id = "title") 
private WebElement title;
```

But I am trying something like this: (It does not work)

```
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(By.id("title")) 
private By titleBy;
```

Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: trying to instantiate the By element so it would make easier to use it on different methods in my page class webDriver.findElement(By.id("xxxx")), so I can do webDriver.findElement(element) and so on....

Comment: if you can use `@FindBy` to find elements, why do you need to use `webDriver.findElement()`. It seems like you are trying to circumvent the whole purpose behind using `pagefactory`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "q")
private WebElement searchBox;
```

Right? It is placed here https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory

Comment: I guess the searchBox still a WebElement. I am trying to instantiate a By element. I can do it by doing this way: @FindBy(id = "title") 
private By title; But it is always null.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, (from your comment )

Its is not advisable to use

```
 webDriver.findElement(By.id("xxxx")), or webDriver.findElement(element)
```

While you use Page factory. Just go ahead perform operations directly and the webelements wiring will be taken care by **PageFactory.initElements()** method.

Please [check this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) for more details.

Coming to your question,

As per [this official doc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html),

```
@FindBy(By.id("title"))
```

doesn't exists. If you need an alternative try **How** class as suggested by olyv.